# Syntax for returning the final occurance of a string within a grouping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

```
Date_Time      Position Trade
7/16/2018 13:00 Long    1
7/16/2018 13:30 Flat    1
7/16/2018 14:00 Flat    1
7/16/2018 14:30 Long    2
7/16/2018 15:00 Long    2
7/16/2018 15:30 Long    2
7/16/2018 17:00 Short   3
7/16/2018 17:30 Short   3
7/16/2018 18:00 Short   3
7/16/2018 18:30 Short   3
7/16/2018 19:00 Short   3
7/16/2018 19:30 Long    4
7/16/2018 20:00 Long    4
7/16/2018 20:30 Long    4
7/16/2018 21:00 Long    4
7/16/2018 21:30 Short   5
7/16/2018 22:00 Short   5
7/16/2018 22:30 Short   5
7/16/2018 23:00 Short   5
7/16/2018 23:30 Short   5
7/17/2018 0:00  Short   5
7/17/2018 0:30  Short   5
7/17/2018 1:00  Short   5
7/17/2018 1:30  Short   5
7/17/2018 2:00  Short   5
7/17/2018 2:30  Long    6
```

I have a dataframe that looks like the above. I'm trying to create a function that returns a series grouped by the trades.

```
def compact_view(groupby):
agg_dict = {'EntryTime': groupby.iloc[0, :].name,
            'Trade Type': groupby['Position'].iat[0],
            'Size': groupby['Size'].iat[0],


            }

return pd.Series(agg_dict, index=['EntryTime', 'Trade Type', 'Size', 'ExitTime'])
compact_results = results.groupby(['Trades']).apply(compact_view)
```

I'm having trouble with the syntax for one of the series items.

I'd like to have a line called 'ExitTime' which would go in my dictionary in the compact_view function and returns the  index value of the row below the final position of the word 'Long' or 'Short' within each set of trade numbers.

so the first one would be 7/16/2018 13:30. The second would be,7/16/2018 17:00 etc etc

Expected Results:

```
Trades  EntryTime   Trade Type  Size    ExitTime
0   7/16/2018 3:30  Flat    0   
1   7/16/2018 13:00 Long    5   7/16/2018 13:30
2   7/16/2018 14:30 Long    5   7/16/2018 17:00
3   7/16/2018 17:00 Short   -5  7/16/2018 19:30
4   7/16/2018 19:30 Long    5   7/16/2018 21:30
5   7/16/2018 21:30 Short   -5  7/17/2018 2:30
6   7/17/2018 2:30  Long    5   7/17/2018 4:30
```

Comment: What do you want to do in the case where the entire group is only `Long` or `Short`, like for `Trade=2` Within the group, there really is no row below the final position of `Long`

Comment: in that case it would return the index value of the first row of trade=3. (so if they are all Short, it returns the final row shifted(-1)

Comment: @novawaly - Can youvadd expected output?

Comment: added the expected @jezrael

Comment: I don't think it can be done with the agg dictionary. Your result for one group can be based on the values contained within another group. Probably best to find the indices then use `df.loc[]` to get the values.

Comment: @ALollz - Be free answering, I dont understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUUC, within each Trade group you need to find the last index of the occurrence of either `Long` or `Short` and then grab the row below that.

There are a lot of things that can go wrong, and I don't know how you want to handle that.

- What happens if a `Trade` group never contains `Long` or `Short`. (Currently this will throw and `IndexError`)
- What do you want to do if the last row in your `DataFrame` is `Long` or `Short`

So you can add exceptions to deal with these cases separately (like try and except). At least from your sample data, You can do something like:

```
ids = df.reset_index().groupby('Trade').apply(lambda x: x[x.Position.isin(['Long', 'Short'])].index[-1]+1)
df.reset_index().reindex(ids)['Date_Time']
```

Output:

```
1    2018-07-16 13:30:00
6    2018-07-16 17:00:00
11   2018-07-16 19:30:00
15   2018-07-16 21:30:00
25   2018-07-17 02:30:00
26                   NaT
Name: Date_Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now you can just join these to your aggregation result if needed. As you can see my last line is `NaT` because there is no row after the last `Long` value for group 6 in your `DataFrame`

One safer way might be:

```
def next_id(x):
    try:
        return x[x.Position.isin(['Long', 'Short'])].index[-1]+1
    except IndexError:
        pass

ids = df.reset_index().groupby('Trade').apply(lambda x: next_id(x))
```

Comment: so i will always contain a long or short because the trade counter is set to reset on one of those but this def solves the issues. So i do this outside of my compact view function?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that your aggregation result can have more than one row per unique trade. This complicates the join

Comment: Seems like you might need something like `compact_results.loc[compact_results.Trade !=  'Flat', 'ExitTime'] = df.reindex(ids)['Date_Time'].values`

Comment: I keep getting this: ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq.

Comment: @novawaly, `Date_Time` must be your index then. See my edits, I added `.reset_index` which should fix it.

Comment: Hm, did you add the reset_index there too? It worked with me just copying the data and setting `Date_Time` as the index before applying my code.

Comment: just to wrap this up - i was able to get it to work by using this for the join: compact_results['ExitTime'] = results.reset_index().reindex(ids)['Date_Time'].values

Comment: not sure if that ruins something else but seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the last row in a block using pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates():

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Position','Trade'],keep='last')
```

So to get the next row indices:

```
row_indices = [x+1 for x in df.drop_duplicates(
    subset=['Position','Trade'],keep='last').index.get_values()]
```